# Code for contact page to send Email ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have contact page with code and i want that if user click on `Send Message` `Button` then email should send to my domain email address.Eg :mail@mydomain.com.ASP.Net `Button` code is that.

Here is my `button` `Sub` where i want to write code:

```
protected void sendmsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //main code for email page

    }
    catch
    {
        //If the message failed at some point, let the user know

    }
}
```

Comment: So, What do you actually want?

Comment: i search and try many code but i fail .i want code if use click on `send message` `button` then email should receive to my domain email address. i tried that code but not working .

Comment: `i tried that code but not working` - Is it really all that surprising? You have an empty try/catch inside of click handler with no real functional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get that code. But here's how it starts.
You can call below function on SendEmail button click.

**NOTE-** SendTo can be the same as admin_email in case you want the recipient and the sender are same. In your case it'll be the same.

```
       public bool SendMail(string SendTo, string Subject, string Body)
    {
        try
        {
            string admin_email = "email"
            string admin_emailpwd = "password"

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(SendTo);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(admin_email);
            mail.Subject = Subject;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "SMTP.gmail.com";
          //  smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(admin_email, admin_emailpwd);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i mean client will send email to me.i am owner of website and i have contact page.user visit to my page and there is contact page.if user fill the form and click on send button then mail i should receive the mail.Every website have contact page and i have too.

Comment: That means you are the client and its your website. The above code will work perfectly. Try it. Fill in your email and password in admin_email and admin_password. And in SendTo- fill in your email.
That should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827654/asp-net-contact-form-output-to-email-and-access-database