# ASP.NET Contact form - output to localhost sql server database - unable to connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on an ASP.NET site and I am trying to write to a local instance of a SQL Server 2012. The server is (localdb)\MyInstance. The database is "cms".

In my root web.config file, I have added the connection settings:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add
name="myDBConnection"
connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MyInstance;Database=cms;User ID=sa;password=local;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In the contact.aspx.cs file, I am using this to test the connection:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBConnection"].ToString());
connection.Open();
if ((connection.State & ConnectionState.Open) > 0) {
  Response.Write("Connection OK!");
  connection.Close();
} else {
  Response.Write("No Connection!");
}
```

But, each time I test, I get "No connection" error. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've gone over the settings based on this post: [ASP.NET Contact Form - output to email and access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827654/asp-net-contact-form-output-to-email-and-access-database). I also test using this code snippet: http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/SQL/TestSQLConnection.aspx

I suspect there is something not correct about the format of the connection string in the web.config file and have tried various formats from http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/
but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you connect use sql-server management studio? What error you get? error code will help you to solve the problem!

Comment: Yes - I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to work with the db. Unfortunately, I'm new to ASP.NET so I don't know how to research where the problem is between my local site to my local db. Are there logs that I can look at that would have more details?

Comment: Do you use (localdb)\MyInstance to connect to database using Managment Studio, also ensure you use right username and password

Comment: When I open Management Studio, I see 
Server Name: (localdb)\MyInstance; Authentication: SQL Server Authentication; Login: sa; Password: (I cleared it out and manually typed in the password above to confirm I was remembering it correctly).  I click Connect and get in just fine.

Comment: You can try using other connection string format check it here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx and here,  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: I did more research and was able to find in the Event Viewer Application logs that show this error: "Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user." Thank you for above links - I will research there, as well. Your help is very much appreciated!